# I want to check if my player holds a specific item upon entering a room

Tags: java

I'm making the "World of Zuul" text based adventure game right now, and I would like to make it so that upon entering a room it will check if my player holds a specific item in the inventory. This is what I have so far for inventory code (Player class):

```
/**
 * Gets an item from the inventory
 */
public Item getInventoryItem(String itemName)
{
    Item item = inventory.get(itemName);
    currentWeight -= item.itemWeight();
    inventory.remove(itemName);
    return item;
}

/**
 * Lists all the items currently in the inventory
 */
public String listInventory()
{
    String itemList = "";
    for(String key : inventory.keySet())
    {
        String item = inventory.get(key).showName();
        itemList += " -" + item;
    }
    return "Your inventory contains \n" + itemList;
}

/**
 * Adds an item to the inventory
 */
public void addItemToInventory(String itemName, Item item)
{
    if(item.itemWeight() + currentWeight <maxWeightInv)
    {
        inventory.put(itemName, item);
        currentWeight += item.itemWeight();
        System.out.println(itemName + " was added to your inventory.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You can't carry this");
    }
}
```

So I'm honestly wondering how I could make it so that it first checks if a player has a specific item in the inventory (in this case it would be a sword) before entering a room. I have not really tried something yet since I don't really know how to start (Game class):

```
/**
 * Exceptions upon entering Room15
 */
private void Room15()
{
    player.getInventoryItem("Sword");
    if(inventory.contains("Sword"))
    {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the game and your freedom!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Hurry back and find a sword!!!");
    }  
}
```

I hope I have given enough info about what exactly I would like to accomplish. I just need a way of checking if the player holds an item. I can pretty much finish the rest on my own.

Comment: What is the class structure? It seems like your first block of code is in a Player class from the looks of it, but from your second block of code it is not clear whether that is in a separate class and if so, how it references the Player  class.

Comment: Ah you are right sorry. I have put the second block of code in Game class. Wasn't sure where to put it honestly.

Comment: I doubt your decision of implementing retrieval of the item from an inventory  as if a character takes it and throws it away. Where's the operation of looking through the bags (not the one that prints something, but the one that's convenient for you).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't really have an operation like that in the code. It's not necessary I guess. The player just needs a specific item in the inventory and when he does it prints one thing and if he doesn't another thing.

Comment: @RikRodel, if it is not necessary, then you wouldn't have asked the question. It clearly is necessary, the actual question is: why wouldn't you write code that is convenient for you to use?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov probably because I'm really inexperienced

Comment: @RikRodel, but what about my first question? Your method which reads `getInventoryItem` in reality acts like `throwAwayItem` (and will fail if there's no such item). This is't even a matter of experience, that's just a common sense: actions should hint at what they do in their name.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method like this in your Player class:

```
public boolean hasItemInInventory(String itemName)
{
   return inventory.containsKey(itemName);
}
```

Then you could modify your Game class method:

```
private void Room15()
{
    if(player.hasItemInInventory("Sword"))
    {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the game and your freedom!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Hurry back and find a sword!!!");
    }  
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I'll keep trying, thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what is not working? Are you getting an exception?